# Replace text using wildcards

Tags: excel, wildcard

I have a spreadsheet with thousand rows of product details. On a column of sizes the cells have this type of value:

> ;XXS (out of stock);XS;S (out of stock);M (out of stock);L;XL;

I need to remove the values that are out of stock, so I do a Ctrl+F and replace ";*(out of stock);" by ";" but then it replaces everything not to the next semi-colon but to the first semi-colon.

So

> ;XXS (out of stock);XS;S (out of stock);M (out of stock);L;XL;

becomes

> ;L;XL;

How can I use wildcards to get a result such as:

> ;XS;L;XL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 'column of sizes' is column A with the data starting in row 2 then run this routine.

```
Sub del_Out_of_Stock()
    Dim rw As Long, str As String, str2 As String, v As Long, vSZs As Variant

    str = "(out of stock)"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Cells(rw, 1)
                vSZs = Split(.Value2, Chr(59))
                For v = LBound(vSZs) To UBound(vSZs)
                    If CBool(InStr(1, vSZs(v), str, vbTextCompare)) Then _
                        vSZs(v) = vbNullString
                Next v
                str2 = Join(vSZs, Chr(59))
                Do While CBool(InStr(1, str2, Chr(59) & Chr(59))): str2 = Replace(str2, Chr(59) & Chr(59), Chr(59)): Loop
                .Value = str2
            End With
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

You will likely have to a) change the worksheet name, b) change the column index number and possibly c) change the starting row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I guess it wasn't possible with wildcards only.